# Jboss/Tomcat monitor

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm looking for a tool (in linux) that can montior a tomcat/jboss process and if the process fails, I can respawn either or both without having to manually ssh into the box, do any house keeping and then start them up again. I'm not too sure if there is a good tool out there that can monitor the health of jboss/tomcat and report on it's performance. I know jvisualvm gives you various tools, but I'm looking for a disaster recovery solution that is a bit higher level than jvisualvm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp) is an application that wraps your Java process and installs it in the system using service (Windows) or daemon (Linux). It pings the VM periodically and restarts it when it does not respond. Worked for us in production with several application, including Tomcat, JBoss, Mule, etc. Actually Mule ESB is even bundled with this application in the distribution.

Also you don't have to run the application manually when the system starts.

Comment: community edition : linux 64 bit : not available. who does use 32 bit, nowadays ? sigh !!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on a daemon to do this and more, since JOPR nor naggios didn't do what we needed, but those are good tools you could use. I'm not sure but JOPR (or whatever is called today) can restart your servers in case something goes wrong.

A custom made solution as we're working on shouldn't take you more than a week. The main problem, is that to start either JBoss or Tomcat you have to call the startup scripts. But the startup script will restart the service if the exit code is 10, something like this:

```
while $? -ne 10; do
  start_jboss
done
```

So, this daemon which is made in Java uses JMX to connect to the JBoss server and tells JBoss to go down and exit with status code 10 using a method in a MBean. I'm at home, so I'm not sure the exact name of the MBean you have to call for this but I'll provide more info tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) to control the launch of Tomcat/JBoss.